# Run console EXE remotely with PowerShell and get its process ID and stdout

Tags: powershell

I use PowerShell to run a console EXE on a remote server and see its output like this:

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName %SERVER_NAME% -ScriptBlock { Set-Location "%EXE_DIR%" ; .\MyExe.exe %EXE_ARGS% }
```

This works, but gives me no way to kill the process, except connecting to the server via RDP. If I could just save its process ID to a file I should be able to kill it using `Stop-Process`. I tried this:

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName %SERVER_NAME% -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -NoNewWindow -PassThru -Wait -WorkingDirectory "%EXE_DIR%" "%EXE_DIR%\MyExe.exe" "%EXE_ARGS%" }
```

The process runs, but now I don't see its standard output! When I use Start-Process locally (without Invoke-Command) I see the output.

How can I get both the process ID and the standard output/error?

Comment: Look into jobs. `get-help about_Jobs`, and -AsJob, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [background job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can either start a local job to invoke a command on a remote host:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Location 'C:\some\folder'
    & 'C:\path\to\your.exe' $args
  } -ArgumentList $args
} -ArgumentList $argument_list
```

or open a session to a remote host and start a local job there:

```
Enter-PSSession -Computer $computer

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  Set-Location 'C:\some\folder'
  & 'C:\path\to\your.exe' $args
} -ArgumentList $argument_list

Exit-PSSession
```

Job output can be received via [`Receive-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849718.aspx):

```
while ($job.HasMoreData) {
    Receive-Job $job
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
```

You can terminate it via its `StopJob()` method:

```
$job.StopJob()
```

[`Remove-Job`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849742.aspx) removes the job from the job list:

```
Remove-Job $job
```

Comment: Thanks, running a job remotely sounds like a promising idea, but how do I keep getting its output while it runs? `Receive-Job` just gives me the output so far. `Wait-Job` waits without printing output. Basically, I want the same behaviour as if the EXE was running locally in a console window.